# Logout in one application cause logout in another one

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two different web applications hosted in same server .

and in one application i have link to the second one .

If a user login in first application and click the link to second one ,
the user automatically login as i pass the login information through query string .

The Problem :

If the user click on logout button in any of these application , automatically loose session in the other one too

Why this happen ? How can i overcome this ?

Comment: Are you guys using cookies and are they the same between the two sites

Comment: I suggest you to avoid using same session name for different projects or do not run the projects concurrently which have same cookie data or session data.

Comment: How do you do authentication in your application?

Comment: I dont Use cookies . I create a GUID in the first application and send it via the query string and authenticate it with a service from the second application

Comment: session will be only one i think because you are going from one application to another

Comment: @Fool and what this GUID contains ?

Comment: @KrzysztofBranicki i use System.Guid    https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @shreesha  " session will be only one  "  My two applications are in different apppool in iis..then how ?

Comment: Got the issue , Thank you guys for your valuable time

Comment: @fool can you tell your solution other then below accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the Issue , I have same domain name for both of these applications .
As it has same domain name the cookie and session ids are same . Hosted these applications with different domain names and the issue gone ..!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Forms Authentication you should change cookie name in `web.config`

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".SOMENAME" requireSSL="false" protection="All" loginUrl="~/Security/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
```